# Drawing opacity on a transparent Form C#

Tags: c#, gdi

I have a form that is transparent. (done simply by matching the background color, and transparency key.

When attempting to draw things that are transparent, it simply does not work. As the alpha variable gets closer to 0, the color drawn simply gets closer to the original background color of the form.

```
SolidBrush opaqueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255));
SolidBrush semiTransBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 0, 255));
SolidBrush superTransBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(10, 0, 0, 255));
```

using these 3 brushes to draw on a regular form would result in the desired effect. But using it on my transparent form simply matches superTransBrush with my transparencyKey/ Background color, and the semiTransBrush is somewhere between my desired color and the background. Anyway around this?

Comment: To clarify - if you set your BG/transparent colour to green and your brush is blue, does an alpha value of 128 give a mix of blue and green?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - _As the alpha variable gets closer to 0, the color drawn simply gets closer to the original background color of the form._ Indeed, that is how it is; how else would it be?? Only the __one exact transparency key color__ is made transparent. Any other pixels are not. No way around that. You could try picking a color like (254,254,254,254) as the key color but then still white will enter the mix.. - Also: Why did you tag `GDI` instead of `GDI+`??

Comment: Looks like you're targetting WPF? Just a point that may be of use to you.I once had an issue with a transparancy and the bit of the puzzle I was missing was this: the apparent colour of the thing on top is the sum of what's underneath it. The final colour you see is more like putting pieces of coloured glass on top of one another than one layer overriding the next.

Comment: Looks to me like targetting Windows Forms, rather than WPF.

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be a way around this from .NET Forms itself.

The definition of [alpha blending in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e3f5k4xc(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> The alpha value indicates the transparency of the color — the extent
>   to which the color is **blended with the background color**. Alpha values
>   range from 0 through 255, where 0 represents a fully transparent
>   color, and 255 represents a fully opaque color.
>
> Alpha blending is a
>   pixel-by-pixel blending of source and background color data. Each of
>   the three components (red, green, blue) of a given source color is
>   **blended with the corresponding component of the background color**
>   according to the following formula:

```
displayColor = sourceColor × alpha / 255 + backgroundColor × (255 – alpha) / 255
```

Notice there's no consideration given to the transparency of the background itself when calculating alpha blending.

The closest workaround would be to set the `CompositingMode` to source copy:

```
e.Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
```

This prevents blending the transparent colour with the background colour, so your brush will be blue, instead of a blend of blue + background colour. Your brush will still be opaque, however.

Answer (score 0):

**Background**

Windows Forms is build on top of GDI and GDI+.

GDI is a very old technology dating back a long way in Windows history, and wasn't designed to be alpha aware.

GDI+ Which was shipped with WindowsXP and successors was designed to complement GDI with alpga blending, anti-aliasing, and other such features you'd expect from a modern 2D graphics library.

Unfortunately, GDI+ does not make GDI alpha aware, it only fakes alpha in some cases.

**Your Scenario**

In your case, it's faking the alpha channel, and drawing the SolidBrush color onto your form, before performing the transparency operation to the form, thus, the renderer sees a different color to the one you specified for transparency and ignores it.

**My Scenario**

In my case, I was trying to draw a drop shadow to a borderless form. It worked. but it was buggy as hell.

I have achieved what you're trying to do, but you won't do it purely with Managed C#/.NET; you're going to have to call into GDI/GDI+ directly using P/Invoke.